# Toggle:checked is not working on IE11

Tags: html, css, less

I am trying to toggle modals by using checkbox. Toggle works well in all browsers except IE11. Apparently this line of code ".Toggle:checked+ .AccessAccount" is not supported by IE11.

```css
.Toggle {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  
}
.AccessAccount{opacity: 0;}
.Toggle:checked+ .AccessAccount {
  opacity: 1;
 
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="Toggle" id="Account">
<div class="AccessAccount">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
```

Any solutions would be appreciated :)

Comment: With **display: none;** in **.Toggle** class, how will you see the Checkbox? If the intention is to hide the DIV, then simply add **display: none;** to **.Toggle:checked + .AccessAccount** class and the code works in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is not the problem. It is supposed to be hidden and by clicking on the icon it is getting visible. The issue is this line of code ".Toggle:checked + .Idm" which never works in IE11 but works absolutely fine in all the other browsers

Comment: @Negin what is the thing that is not working ? You can't just say, it's not working!
Is it the opacity that is not working? 
is it the flex? 
is it the pointer-events?

Comment: I can't get this code to work for me in Chrome. `.display-flex();` is not valid CSS. There is no way to test the checkbox because you can't see it. You mention that "*by clicking on the icon it is getting visible*" - what icon? Please give us a **[Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** and tell us **what isn't working** and **what your desired result is**.

Comment: @Milad: Thanks for your time but If you read my description carefully:
"I am trying to toggle modals by using checkbox" it is completely clear what is not working!! If it was opacity or flex or pointer I would specifically mention them ! Anyway I have added some more info to make it more clear.

Comment: just tested the provided snippet, and it works perfectly fine in IE11...

Comment: It works on IE 11 for me either

Comment: I see that now you have removed **display: none;** from **Toggle** class. I ran the snippet in Chrome, Edge and IE 11 it works everywhere.